# How to apply box filter on integral image? (SURF)

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, surf

Assuming that I have a grayscale (8-bit) image and assume that I have an integral image created from that same image.
Image resolution is `720x576`. According to SURF algorithm, each octave is composed of 4 box filters, which are defined by the number of pixels on their side. 
The
    first octave uses filters with `9x9, 15x15, 21x21 and 27x27` pixels.
 The
    second octave uses filters with `15x15, 27x27, 39x39 and 51x51` pixels.
The third octave uses filters with `27x27, 51x51, 75x75 and 99x99` pixels. If the image is sufficiently large and I guess **720x576 is big enough (right??!!)**, a fourth octave is added, `51x51, 99x99, 147x147 and 195x195`. These
    octaves partially overlap one another to improve the quality of the interpolated results.

```
// so, we have:
//
// 9x9   15x15  21x21   27x27
// 15x15 27x27  39x39   51x51
// 27x27 51x51  75x75   99x99
// 51x51 99x99 147x147 195x195
```

The questions are:
**What are the values in each of these filters? Should I hardcode these values, or should I calculate them?
 How exactly (numerically) to apply filters to the integral image?**

Also, for calculating the Hessian determinant I found two approximations:
`det(HessianApprox) = DxxDyy − (0.9Dxy)^2` and
`det(HessianApprox) = DxxDyy − (0.81Dxy)^2`
**Which one is correct?**
(Dxx, Dyy, and Dxy are Gaussian second order derivatives).

Answer (score 5):

I had to go back to the [original paper](http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/~surf/eccv06.pdf) to find the precise answers to your questions.

**Some background first**

SURF leverages a common Image Analysis approach for regions-of-interest detection that is called blob detection.
The typical approach for blob detection is a difference of Gaussians.
There are several reasons for this, the first one being to mimic what happens in the visual cortex of the human brains.

The drawback to difference of Gaussians (DoG) is the computation time that is too expensive to be applied to large image areas.

In order to bypass this issue, SURF takes a simple approach. A DoG is simply the computation of two Gaussian averages (or equivalently, apply a Gaussian blur) followed by taking their difference.
A quick-and-dirty approximation (not so dirty for small regions) is to approximate the Gaussian blur by a box blur.

A box blur is the average value of all the images values in a given rectangle. It can be computed efficiently via *integral images*.

**Using integral images**

Inside an integral image, *each pixel value is the sum of all the pixels* that were *above* it and on its *left* in the original image.
The top-left pixel value in the integral image is thus 0, and the bottom-rightmost pixel of the integral image has thus the sum of all the original pixels for value.

Then, you just need to remark that the box blur is equal to the sum of all the pixels inside a given rectangle (not originating in the top-lefmost pixel of the image) and apply the following simple geometric reasoning.

If you have a rectangle with corners ABCD (top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right), then the value of the box filter is given by:

```
boxFilter(ABCD) = A + D - B - C,
```

where A, B, C, D is a shortcut for IntegralImagePixelAt(A) (B, C, D respectively).

**Integral images in SURF**

SURF is not using box blurs of sizes 9x9, etc. directly.
What it uses instead is several orders of Gaussian derivatives, or Haar-like features.

Let's take an example. Suppose you are to compute the 9x9 filters output. This corresponds to a given sigma, hence a fixed scale/octave.

The sigma being fixed, you center your 9x9 window on the pixel of interest. Then, you compute the output of the 2nd order Gaussian derivative in each direction (horizontal, vertical, diagonal). The Fig. 1 in the paper gives you an illustration of the vertical and diagonal filters.

**The Hessian determinant**

There is a factor to take into account the scale differences. Let's believe the paper that the determinant is equal to:

```
Det = DxxDyy - (0.9 * Dxy)^2.
```

Finally, the determinant is given by: `Det = DxxDyy - 0.81*Dxy^2`.

Comment: OK, I understand that, but there are 4 octaves with 4 filters. Call me stupid, but I still cannot see how to apply 9x9 filter for the first octave. How to calculate A, B, C and D? Or maybe A is a 9x9 square, B is 15x15 square, C is 21x21 square and D is 27x27 square?

Comment: A pixel A of the integral image is the sum of all pixels of the original image from the top-left corner down to A. Therefore A + D - B - C is.... (draw yourself a picture to see what you get)

Comment: @Francesco, I hear you, but such ABCD rectangle can be of any size placed anywhere within integral image. Does it mean that ABCD = 9x9 square? If it is, how to position that ABCD square over integral image in order to calculate A+D-B-C? In other words, vertex 'A' should be placed where?

Comment: Ignoring the border (for the moment), the sum is the output of the box filter for the center pixel of the square. For the borders, you have to choose which convention to follow for the convolution: clamp-to-edge, clamp-to-zero, mirror, crop-invalid, etc. Each has its advantages and drawbacks.

Comment: @Francesco, while calculating integral image I used zero values for the non-existing pixels. So, are you telling me that I should place the center of the 9x9 filter over each position in the integral image and calculate the output?

Comment: Refer to Fig. 1 in the paper. Put the 9x9 shape on your current pixel. Whenever a rectangle has a +1 inside means take the box value in the rectangle. Whenever a rectangle has a -1 means take minus the box value in the rectangle. Then, add these 2 values, this is the output of THIS 9x9 filter for THIS pixel. Do this for all the 9x9 filters that you consider. If people cannot answer to what you want, please consider rephrasing your question instead of starting name calling. Imo, the best practical book is Modern Computer  Vision (Forsyth-Ponce).

Answer (score 0):

Look at page 17 of this document
http://www.sci.utah.edu/~fletcher/CS7960/slides/Scott.pdf

If you made a code for normal Gaussian 2D convolution, just use the box filter as a Gaussian kernel and the input image will be the same original image not integral image. The results from this method will be same with the one you asked.