# Box filter approximations for the oriented gabor filters

Tags: image, algorithm, image-processing, processing-efficiency, imagefilter

I'm currently reading this paper: [Approximations in the HMAX Model](http://cbcl.mit.edu/publications/ai-publications/2011/MIT-CSAIL-TR-2011-021.pdf), I'm particularly interested in the approximation of the gabor filter using Box filters.

Last year I developed a synthetic fingerprint generator (you can see some of it here [How to convolve an image with different gabor filters adjusted according to the local orientation and density using FFT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878754/how-to-convolve-an-image-with-different-gabor-filters-adjusted-according-to-the)).

But the biggest flaw in the generator is the time it takes to apply the gabor filter, I have been researching how to implement a separable version of the filter but  have failed horribly since mathematics is not my forte.
Now this seem better for my needs than the separable filter, since it seems to be faster and the results seem good enough for what I need. But I don’t understand how to implement the box filtering for gabor from the equation in that paper.

It goes as follow:

> In this section we attempt to perform a grosser approximation of the
>   ﬁlter to achieve signiﬁcantly higher eﬃciency. Currently, the S1 layer
>   in the model, consists of simple line detectors that are modeled using
>   oriented Gabor ﬁlters. However, oriented lines can be represented
>   using much simpler represented such as box ﬁlters as shown in Figure
>   5. These ﬁlters have very sparse derivatives allowing us to compute convolution quite eﬃciently. The convolution of the image with the
>   ﬁlters B(x, y) can be eﬃciently computed using the ﬁlter’s derivatives
>   as follows.
>
> [image: http://s18.postimg.org/ozlw5kn55/formula.png]
>
> The second derivative of the box ﬁlter consists of just impulses and
>   therefore needs to be evaluated at only four points for every position
>   in the image. The integral image can also be eﬃciently computed using
>   single pass algorithm as outlined in [5, 1]. The cost of convolution
>   using this approximation is O(N2c), c=4. Unlike other approximations,
>   the computational cost does not depend on the size of the ﬁlter at
>   all!.

What are those terms? Is that the integral of the integral of the image? I’m sorry if this is like super basic stuff I’m asking, but I honestly have no clue :(.

Comment: `d^2 B(x,y) / dxdy` is the 2nd derivative of B(x,y) in x then y, `// I(x,y)` is the second Integration

Comment: @Khaled A Khunaifer - what does it mean in digital signal processing? knowing the symbols is pretty trivial.

Comment: @hellfire769 In computer science terms, derivative will replace having the process linear into a general formula over the whole line, while integration is the inverse technically

Comment: [This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19672315/7328782) has a much better answer than the one currently accepted here (which does not address the question at all). This question asks about “integral images”, a Google search for that term would be a good first step to learn more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rhs equation in your question is the infinitesimal description of convolution - you have the convolution operator **" * "** which is applied over a 2D subrange of the image - that 2d subrange is expressed as an 2D integral.
The discrete description is similar, but with 2D subrange expressed with summation operator using the sigma notation "Σ". instead of 2D integral, it is applied as  "ΣΣ" (I don't know how to put math notation here).

Naive Implementation of the convolution is using 2 loops - in each point in the image you sum the kernel values multiplied with the that point and neighboring points -

**P(x+c/2) = P(x)*C(1)+P(x+1)*C(2)...+P(x+c)*C(c)  (c is the size of the kernel)**.
 The process is similar to long multiplication or polynomial with polynomial multiplication.

Basically convolution can be applied in various ways, one way is straight forward (summation), or by transformation to other spaces (Fast Fourier Transform) - [Convolution Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem).

**FFT time is O(NlogN)**.
using FFT for convolution is efficient if the size of the kernel is big.
Otherwise, **if kernel size is small : O(c) < O(logN) -  convolution is faster**.
Since filter size is 4 - go with straight forward convolution.

Also you can parallel the convolution (via cuda, open-mp, etc...)

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer, I have already implemented both the direct convolution and the FFT of the gabor filter, I was looking to implement this box filter approximation of the Gabor filter, but basically, It doesnt show how the box filter is aproximating the gabor filter, but just the general notion of convolution?

Comment: @AngelCastillo - about the filter approximation - I had a brief look at the paper - the approximation appears at section 2.1: Aproximations at the S1 Layer - separable Filters. It is the first layer, it shows the approximation to the Gabor Box - see the development of the exponent equation to f(x) g (y) (7 , 8). There is a Rotation matrix to obtain all the filters. I would also for simplicity set the anisotropy factor to 1 (for a start)

Comment: Hey @chook, thanks for all the help, following the formula for f(x), I got this "x=exp(-(x^2)/(2* (sigma*sigma)))*exp(sqrt(-1)*x*cos(theta))", notice the "sqrt(-1)" (ix), I cant do that in C++ without resorting to complex numbers, is there a way to change that for something equivalent? Im not sure what to make out of it, even if I use complex numbers, the result of the whole expresion will be a complex number and i dont know how to filter using those. Thanks for your time.